# I can not find a way to set the ons-popover background-color

Tags: popover, onsen-ui

Is there any way to change the background color of the ons-popovers? Changing the style did not seem to work and I don't see an attribute to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Onsen 1.x and Onsen 2 prior to beta.8:

```
.popover__content  {
  background-color: red;
}

.popover__top-arrow,
.popover__bottom-arrow,
.popover__left-arrow,
.popover__right-arrow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

Change `red` with the color you want.